# Get Customers email address on custom adminhtml customer tab

Tags: adminhtml, magento-ce

I create a custom tab on the admin customer edit page. However what I want to do is get the customers email address to display on the page.

I tried to look for the code that produces the Account information tab but could not find it.

I tried something like in my
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customertab/tab.phtml
however this seems to just break the page meaning just the first tab loads the rest of the page is blank white.

```
<div id="customer_info_tabs_customer_edit_tab_action_content">
<div class="entry-edit">
<div class="entry-edit-head">
<h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend">Contact Customer</h4>
</div>
<div id="group_fields4" class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
<div class="hor-scroll">
<table class="form-list" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getEmail; ?> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you do any other code  for this?then please put that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way of getting email address in customer edit section (admin side) is shown below.

```
$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
$emailAddress =  $customer->getEmail();
```

Magento will register the customer whose details are editing via admin in the controller action itself (refer : `Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController::editAction()`) and hence you can get the customer using *Mage-Registry* as I shown above and get the email address.